# move packages under root with setuptools

Tags: python, package, setuptools, distutils

this is a (part of my) project structure:

```
<root>
|- src
     |-main
         |-python
             |- common
             |- constans
             |- controller
             |- resources
             |- rest
 - setup.py
```

I want to make my packages 'common', 'mappers' and 'rest' available under the root (which will make referencing less verbose). It should look like this:

```
   <root>
     - common
     - mappers
     - rest
     - setup.py
```

this is my setup.py file, based on https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='my_project',
      version='0.0.1',
      package_dir={'src.main.python': ''},
      packacges = ['src.main.python']
     )
```

I have A MANIFEST.in file based on an example i found online:

```
include src.main.python fp README COPYING
recursive-include src\main\python *
```

When i use the command `python setup.py sdist` it creates a directory 'dist' under the root with my project in a zip file. my packages (common, mappers and rest) are under `src\main\python` instead of under the root folder. What should be done to get them under the root folder?

Comment: Possibly o/t, but you have a typo in your `setup` call.

Answer (score 0):

I created my project using pybuilder http://pybuilder.github.io/, there is a great tutorial on how to create a project etc. When your project is created and your code is ready to build, go to the root where the build.py file is located and use

```
pyb
```

a target folder is created in the root of your project.
Go to `target/dist/name_of_your_project` there should be a setup.py file.
in this setup file, which pybuilder generated for you, make sure **zip_safe = False**. this is an extract of my setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
          name = 'my_project',
          version = '1.0.dev0',

           ....

          packages = ['my_project', 'my_project.common', 'my_project.mappers', 'my_project.rest'],
          py_modules = ['__init__'],
          classifiers = ['Development Status :: 3 - Alpha', 'Programming Language :: Python'],
          entry_points={
          'console_scripts':
              []
          },
             #  data files
             # package data


          zip_safe=False
    )
```

use the following command here:

```
python setup.py install
```

a folder will be created in your Lib/site-packages based on the information in your setup.py file:

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\my_project-1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg
```

in your site-packages folder there is a file named `easy-install.pth`, there should be an entry with the name of this egg file:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./loggingserver-0.1dev_r0-py2.7.egg
   .....
./my_project-1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

the directories in this file serve as a hook. From within any project you can now reference folders that are the children of my_project-1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg.

so lets say the structure of `my_project-1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg`  is as follows:

```
-my_project
   - common
   - mappers
   - rest
   - EGG_INFO
```

reference common as follows:

```
from my_project import common
```